# Bridge from eth0 to eth1 with static ip

Tags: ethernet, kali, bridge, pi-5

Currently I'm running Kali Linux 2023.4 on a Raspberry Pi 5, and I am attempting to create a network bridge between `eth0` (the onboard Ethernet port) and `eth1` (a USB-to-Ethernet dongle). While I have successfully set up the bridge, I am encountering issues accessing eth0 through `bettercap`. Additionally, I'm unable to assign a static IP to eth0. Any assistance or insights into resolving these challenges would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you're using the word `bridge` in the right context - it's my understanding (and experience) that the bridge has the IP address(es), not bridged devices - i.e. eth0/eth1 in your case won't/can't have IP address(es), since they are bridged, they have the bridge IP address(es)